# Python with Sqlite 3, how to extract only text, without 'u?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, ascii

I have the following code:

```
password_master  = str(self.master_password.text())
username = str(self.comboBox.currentText())
result = c.execute("SELECT * FROM register_table WHERE MASTER = '"+password_master+"' AND USERNAME = '"+username+"'")
if (len(result.fetchall()) > 0):
   print("user found")
   password_check = c.execute("SELECT PASSWORD FROM register_table WHERE USERNAME = '"+username+"' AND MASTER = '"+password_master+"'").fetchall()
   password = str(password_check)
   login(username, password)
```

From the "password_check" query I would like to extract only the text, because I need to pass variable "password" to "login" function.
I tried everything but I always receive the following output:

```
[(u'@-passwordtest-@',)]
```

Is there a way to extract simply

```
passwordtest
```

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Start by **not** using `str()` on the resulting rows. You only need to fetch **one** row, so don't fetch them all either.

Comment: The `u` is not in the data. It's just how python represents the data when you print out a data structure. It is an artifact of the printing (ie: the conversion of the list of data items to a string)

Comment: To elaborate on what @BryanOakley said, it is simply Python's way of telling you that the string in the quotes is a *unicode string*. The `u` is not part of the date, just how it is printed.

Comment: Thank you guys!!!! I stopped when I saw printed the result... Now everything is ok, I also removed fetchall... Many thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 3):

First off, I'll start with the standard [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) warning. Granted, this doesn't look like it's web facing, but still. You should be using bind variables.

Secondly, your query will return an array of values, so you're trying to run the str() function on an array that contains strings. I would replace the lines:

```
password_check = c.execute("SELECT PASSWORD FROM register_table WHERE USERNAME = '"+username+"' AND MASTER = '"+password_master+"'").fetchall()
password = str(password_check)
```

with:

```
results = c.execute("SELECT PASSWORD FROM register_table WHERE USERNAME = '"+username+"' AND MASTER = '"+password_master+"'").fetchone()
password = results[0]
```